# Changed email address

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to help my friend retrieve his account.
His account was under an old email address that does not exist anymore. Is there anyway his account can be retrieved and update the email address?
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Connect to Facebook
2. Sign out of Facebook
3. Clear your browsing history
4. Sign in to Facebook
5. Disconnect your google account
6. Link the google account you want to switch to

Comment: Awesome let me try that. Its on an Iphone does it make a difference?

Comment: Since you can do all those things on an iPhone, it shouldn't.

Comment: Did the directions work?